# Android Telnet tutorial

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, ssh, telnet

Are there any Telnet client source Samples or Tutorials that help Beginners (ME) understand how to open Sockets and develop apps using sockets.

I went through all the samples using Eclipse and various Tutorials online but none of them that I have found seem to work correctly - either old or dead code or just missing information.

I assume I will need to include a java.net jar file but where is it and how do I include it?

using Eclipse I went through the few tutorials but none of them did much more than Hello World and show me how to drag and drop buttons and edit text.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3):

Your answer has basically been given,
If you're using android you're already using java.
Here's the android reference for sockets: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html
I would (like amir) looking at some basic java IO tutorials. There's an ok list of java socket tutorials on oracle's site.

And finally, the best advice...
Go forth and code!

Comment: Yes. being New to android - Eclipse environment.. I asked how to import java into eclipse and then eventually into my android... none of the eclipse help files go through this. I have tried to paste sample java code into my projects src directory and I just get tons of red x's its always missing something or it says dead code or various other errors.

Comment: I will keep at it and eventually get it to convert.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is really not relative to android. java.net is already included in android sdk because android sdk is modification of JDK. Instead of googling or researching android sockets. Just look at how to make socket connections in Java. There is a class call Socket which will allow you to open and transfer data between remote server.

Comment: You are asking really basic java questions. You can look at tutorials on how to make sockets and use 'em in java.

Comment: If I was able to find it why would I ask here?

Comment: Your ability to help somebody is directly related to your desire to actually help them

Comment: I think you are asking people to do the research for you. Googling "java socket" finds http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html This shows you everything you need to do and stop writing smart ass comments. Because the ability of what you want to learn is directly related to how much you read and learn instead of asking others.

Comment: Truth be told I wasn't writing smart #@$ comments however I am sorry you got offended. Thank you for your help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

1st off you've got to use the android SDK to build a correct structure for an android app, then copy/paste your java code. This will take a few or maybe dozens of iterations of attempts depending on the size and complexity of the code you are bringing over. You will have to repeatedly Import all the java and/or android packages needed by your code. Eclipse will attempt to point out what you need but this suggestion isn't always right but frequently it is.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet it's not a simple tcp connection. I use free apache commonse library which provide class for telnet accessing. Otherwise you need create you own class for establishing, and provide telnet session.